# Silverlight: How to start with element being invisible before biding?

Tags: silverlight

So, my stack panel should be hidden or shown depending on the binding to one of the properties on DTO. Problem is that there is a slight delay, so it flashes before it disappears when the property is set to false.

Comment: Post your code. Both the code that defines the StackPanel and the code that sets the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Use the FallbackValue of the binding... It will use the FallbackValue if it can't bind, then when the property gets set, the visibility will change.

```
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding ShowImageVisibility, FallbackValue=Collapsed}">
</StackPanel>
```